# Is the SendChuncked Property missing from System.Net.HttpWebRequest in Silverlight 2?

Tags: silverlight

I need to send large files from silverlight 2 beta 2, so I need to set the sendchuncked property to true, but the property doesn't seem to exist.  I've seen other posts on the internet where people have been able to set this in Silverlight.

I disassebled the .dll at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Reference Assemblies in reflector and have confirmed that the property doesn't exist.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more of research, I was looking at the documentation for ASP.NET.  You need to wire up your own file upload chuncking mechanism.  See Tim Heuer's [great video](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/10/embed-fonts-and-file-upload-in-silverlight-2.aspx) about this topic

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide links to those posts? Maybe they refer to a different of Silverlight, some things have been removed from S2B2.